# Вывести все записи - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Сейчас выводит только уникальные записи

```
SELECT questions.question_name, questions.user_id FROM questions 
INNER JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id  
GROUP BY questions.question_name
```

Если будет одинаковые записи в столбце **question_name**, то они проигнорируются и будет выведена, только одна из них.
Как вывести всё записи, включая и одинаковые, не убирая **GROUP BY questions.question_name**?

Comment: а может их сгруппировать не по question_name, а по id? Так можно?

Comment: Скажите, для чего вам нужна группировка, что вы хотите? Что бы всё записи были? Тогда убирайте, если хотите что бы были все уникальные вопросы от пользователя тогда `questions.user_id, questions.question_name` по этим параметрам

Comment: *Как вывести всё записи, включая и одинаковые, не убирая GROUP BY questions.question_name?* При такой группировке для любого значения questions.question_name в результирующем наборе будет строго одна запись. А потому - **никак**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.question_name, questions.user_id FROM questions 
INNER JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id  
GROUP BY questions.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Перебором массива попробуйте

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    do {   
          $id=$myrow['id'];
          $r1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id!='$id'");
          mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
          $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($r1);
    do {
        if ($myrow['title']==$myrow2['title']) {echo '# '. $myrow['id'].' - '. $myrow['title'].' <br>'; }
         }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($r));
```